# How to get permission to edit files using File object in Android 11 with scoped storage on?

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

In Android 10 scoped storage, forming File object with file path was completely restricted. However based on many feedbacks this was somewhat eased in Android 11 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers). In the video it is mentioned that you can use File object and get access to the file with user consent by requesting the permission to do so.

I am not able to figure out what permission should I be getting to edit the files using File object. I tried SAF, it didn't work.

(I want to edit tags of audio file using ID3 tag editor library which takes input in the form of File. I tried getting permission using SAF it didn't work, I tried to get permission using MediaStore.createWriteRequest() even this didn't work)

Edit 1 : I am getting the file path using MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA column value.

And to put the question in other way, if we get the permission to file using SAF, can we use File object to edit that file (or) is that if you have permission for file via SAF you can use only DocumentFile to edit that file.

Edit 2 : I was able to edit file using DocumentFile when I got the permission using SAF, however I was not able to edit using File object.

Comment: Android 11 behaves nearly as Android versions before 10. So ask read and write storage permission in manifest and add code to let the user confirm those permissions at runtime. Or toggle the storage permission manually in the settings for your app. Having that is a good start.

Comment: @blackapps, Yes I have those permission specified in manifest and I am handling that and things are working fine in below Android 11 (For Android 10 I have opted out of scoped storage). However I am not able to edit files using File object in Android 11 despite getting necessary permission they have specified in the doc.

Comment: Then show your code and start mentioning full path and tell how you obtained that path.